# tradingview: Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back

Tags: pine-script

I'm currently writing an indicator that is using multiple Timeframes. Im only using `box.new` to display the information.
My Goal is to calculate all Releative coordinates, save these in an Array, and then add or update the relative `Box`.

I get this error alot when running the code, but not always. The error on the beginning of a new Bar (see image):
[image]

> Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back

my Code:

```
//@version=4
study("SO_example", overlay=true, max_bars_back=2000)

//help function for Higher Timeframe
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])

//variables
lookback_size = 5
move_ratio = input(title="move_ratio", type=input.float, defval=0.5, minval=-10, maxval=10)
atr_ratio = 0.5
lookback = 3
higher_res = "60"

// Price Data from Higher Timerframe
o = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
h = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
c = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)


//Init Arrays
//Calculations
var drive_detected = array.new_int(0)
var drive_rev_break = array.new_int(0)
var drive_break = array.new_float(0)
var drive_revpoint = array.new_float(0)


//Initialize boxes for coordinates
box_trans = 70
col = color.new(color.red, box_trans)
box[] boxes = array.new_box()
var b0 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0)
array.push(boxes, b0)
var b1 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b1)
var b2 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b2)
var b3 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b3)
var b4 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b4)  


//only look for ordinates based on higher Timeframe
if(is_newbar(higher_res)) 
    
    // condition Calculation
    _tr = h-l
    _move_mean = sma(_tr, lookback)
    _move = sum(_tr, lookback)
    _atr = rma(_tr, 14)
    _change =   c-o 
    _net_change = sum(_change,lookback)
    _ratio = 1-((_move- _net_change)/_move)
    _atr_ratio = (_move_mean/_atr)
    _ratio_p = _ratio>0 ? _ratio : na
    _ratio_n = _ratio<=0 ? abs(_ratio) : na
    condition = _atr_ratio>= atr_ratio and abs(_ratio) > move_ratio    
    
    if condition 
        //save Coordinates
        array.unshift(drive_detected,bar_index)
        array.unshift(drive_break,high)
        array.unshift(drive_revpoint,low)    
        
        //keep  total Coordinates of last 'lookback_size', pop the rest
        if array.size(drive_detected) >lookback_size
            array.pop(drive_detected)
            array.pop(drive_break)
            array.pop(drive_revpoint)     
        bool(na)
                
//draw/update Boxes
if array.size(drive_detected)>=lookback_size  
    for i = 0 to lookback_size-1
        _box = array.get(boxes,i)
        box.set_bottom(_box,array.get(drive_revpoint,i))
        box.set_top(_box,array.get(drive_break,i))
        box.set_left(_box,array.get(drive_detected,i))
        box.set_right(_box,bar_index)
```

I have a Feeling that it is a problem with the Condition Calculation and only calculating on `is_newbar(higher_res)`.
Where am I going wrong? What is the underlying structure that processes the data so that I can understand the error and why its occuring?
Thanks alot!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. We have taken the calcs leading to `condition` outside the `if` block so they are executed on each bar:

```
//@version=4
study("SO_example", overlay=true, max_bars_back=2000)

//help function for Higher Timeframe
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])

//variables
lookback_size = 5
move_ratio = input(title="move_ratio", type=input.float, defval=0.5, minval=-10, maxval=10)
atr_ratio = 0.5
lookback = 3
higher_res = "60"

// Price Data from Higher Timerframe
o = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
h = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
c = security(syminfo.tickerid, higher_res, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)


//Init Arrays
//Calculations
var drive_detected = array.new_int(0)
var drive_rev_break = array.new_int(0)
var drive_break = array.new_float(0)
var drive_revpoint = array.new_float(0)


//Initialize boxes for coordinates
box_trans = 70
col = color.new(color.red, box_trans)
box[] boxes = array.new_box()
var b0 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0)
array.push(boxes, b0)
var b1 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b1)
var b2 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b2)
var b3 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b3)
var b4 = box.new(bar_index, 0, bar_index-2, 0,bgcolor=col,border_width=0 )
array.push(boxes, b4)  


// condition Calculation
_tr = h-l
_move_mean = sma(_tr, lookback)
_move = sum(_tr, lookback)
_atr = rma(_tr, 14)
_change =   c-o 
_net_change = sum(_change,lookback)
_ratio = 1-((_move- _net_change)/_move)
_atr_ratio = (_move_mean/_atr)
_ratio_p = _ratio>0 ? _ratio : na
_ratio_n = _ratio<=0 ? abs(_ratio) : na
condition = _atr_ratio>= atr_ratio and abs(_ratio) > move_ratio    

//only look for ordinates based on higher Timeframe
if(is_newbar(higher_res)) 
    if condition 
        //save Coordinates
        array.unshift(drive_detected,bar_index)
        array.unshift(drive_break,high)
        array.unshift(drive_revpoint,low)    
        
        //keep  total Coordinates of last 'lookback_size', pop the rest
        if array.size(drive_detected) >lookback_size
            array.pop(drive_detected)
            array.pop(drive_break)
            array.pop(drive_revpoint)     
        bool(na)
                
//draw/update Boxes
if array.size(drive_detected)>=lookback_size  
    for i = 0 to lookback_size-1
        _box = array.get(boxes,i)
        box.set_bottom(_box,array.get(drive_revpoint,i))
        box.set_top(_box,array.get(drive_break,i))
        box.set_left(_box,array.get(drive_detected,i))
        box.set_right(_box,bar_index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but moving it out of the ```if``` changes the condition outcome, which is not desirable.
According to [Tradingview Help](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000587849-i-see-pine-cannot-determine-the-referencing-length-of-a-series-try-using-max-bars-back-error/), this is a Bufferproblem. So either my buffer error is in the condition part, or my ```box``` buffer is to smal (is this problem?). Do you know if Boxes also have a max buffer array?
any other Ideas?